# How to initiate a modul in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am making an app using angular and ionic. I am doing facebook login and I have the following code in  app.js init:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['... 'ezfb', 'hljs']);

 app.config('ezfbProvider', function (ezfbProvider) {
         /**
          * Basic setup
          *
          * https://github.com/pc035860/angular-easyfb#configuration
          */
         ezfbProvider.setInitParams({
             appId: 'iddddddd'
         });
     });
```

And I have added a reference to bundle about `angular-easyfb.min.js` and  `angular-easyfb.js`

But I still get an error on the console saying :

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module hljs due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'hljs' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Whats the problem I don't get it ?

Comment: Your app depends on 2 modules: ezfb and hljs. You have installed module ezfb. Why would it install module hljs?

Comment: But i have other dependencies injected before and it works fine :
var app = angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'app.auth' 'ezfb', 'hljs']);

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need to have something call `angular.module("hljs", [...])` before you can create your own module that depends on "hljs".

I'm guessing that you haven't included a "hljs" angular module, or that you have but the script tag for it does not appear before the script tag for your own module.

Comment: The module doesn't need to come before. See http://plnkr.co/edit/inxO6rZp4fRhexjjNxaz?p=preview